# Delete row with Ajax Php Mysql, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to delete rows of dynamic input fields with ajax: Below is my code, which is not working for some reason.

I have ajaxData.php is where I am posting the id to, but I am not sure if the id is actually sent (POST). The row is not getting deleted from the database.

**The Form**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <input value="<?php echo $child_data->child_name; ?>" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-add-child remove-existing-child" style="margin-top:0;" id="<?php echo $child_data->child_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-close fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>

<script>
//AJAX CALL HERE
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".remove-existing-child").click(function() {
      var child_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $el = $(this).parent().parent();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxData.php',
        data: {child_id: child_id},
        success: function(data) {
          if(response=="success") {
                    $el.remove();
                    alert("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED ELEMENT");
                }
        }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

**ajaxData.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db/config.php");
include("includes/function.php");

    $parent = $_GET['parent'];

    if($parent!="") {
      $result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_child where parent_id=$parent");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo "<option value='$row[child_id]'>"; echo $row['name']; echo "</option>";
      }
    }

    // CHILD DELETE REQUEST BELOW

    $delete_child = $_REQUEST['child_id'];

    if(isset($delete_child)) {
      mysql_query("delete from tbl_child where child_id=$delete_child");
      echo "success";
      exit();
    }
    ?>
```

I have pasted all code from my ajaxData.php. Only the code that is below //CHILD DELETE REQUEST BELOW is related to the delete request. The code above that works perfectly well.

Comment: try in the url `?child_id=1 or 1=1` hope it helps..

Comment: Try `$delete_child = $_POST['child_id'];
`

Comment: Mysql_ is deprecated and you should move to either mysqli or PDO.  Especially using prepared statements.

Comment: you can use `parents('selector')` function instead of `parent().parent()`  like `.parents( "div" )` or whatever you want to select.

Comment: I tried url: `ajaxData.php?child_id="+child_id`, I also changed from `$_REQUEST['child_id']` (this is how it was initially, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
data: {child_id: child_id},
```

to

```
data:{'child_id': child_id}, // object attribute name enclosed in 's
```

then finally in the php

```
$delete_child = $_POST['child_id'];
```

Like Musa said.

Comment: I have tried this just now, doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to check where the error is at?

Comment: try to var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but when I added the full url like `url: 'https://xxxxx.xxxx/ajaxData.php?child_id=+child_id` and **things started working**. Can someone explain to me why this works with the full url but not with relative urls?